# Dynamic template reference variable inside ngFor (Angular 9)

Tags: angular, ng-bootstrap, angular-template

How to declare a **dynamic** *template reference variable* inside a `ngFor` element?

I want to use the popover component from ng-bootstrap, the popover code (with Html binding) is as shown:

```html
<ng-template #popContent>Hello, <b>{{name}}</b>!</ng-template>
<button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" [ngbPopover]="popContent" popoverTitle="Fancy content">
    I've got markup and bindings in my popover!
</button>
```

How can I **wrap** those elements inside `ngFor`?

```html
<div *ngFor="let member of members">
    <!-- how to declare the '????' -->
    <ng-template #????>Hello, <b>{{member.name}}</b>!</ng-template>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" [ngbPopover]="????" popoverTitle="Fancy content">
        I've got markup and bindings in my popover!
    </button>
</div>
```

Hmmm... any idea?

Comment: There is no such thing as dynamic reference variables. Why do you think it needs to be dynamic?

Comment: because their tutorial said in order to have html binding inside a popover, then we need to create a `ng-template` and refer it with *template reference variable*, but now I want to use this popover inside a `ngFor` element

Comment: Just do the same. The template variable will be different for each element even when it has the same name.

Comment: What happens if you use the same *ref* for everything? Have you tested it?

Comment: Ha, I never think of that... I will test it now... because I keep thinking on how to declare a ** *template reference variable* with "index"**... will update later after I test it out... :D

Comment: Yeah, it works... I tested it out... thanks for your solution

Answer (score 158):

**Template reference variables are scoped to the template they are defined in. A structural directive creates a nested template and, therefore, introduces a separate scope.**

So you can just use one variable for your template reference

```html
<div *ngFor="let member of members">
  <ng-template #popupContent>Hello, <b>{{member.name}}</b>!</ng-template>
  <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" [ngbPopover]="popupContent" popoverTitle="Fancy content">
      I've got markup and bindings in my popover!
  </button>
</div>
```

and it should work because it has already declared inside `<ng-template ngFor`

**[Plunker Example](https://plnkr.co/edit/e0c2kPlbPXF7gztCw0cN?p=preview)**

For more details see also:

- [angular - conditional duplicate templateref in ng-content with selector](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50073922/angular-conditional-duplicate-templateref-in-ng-content-with-selector/50080838#50080838)

Comment: Note that if you are using an `@ViewChild`, you cannot use this solution (and then should use @AlexBoisselle's one)

Answer (score 40):

This is the best solution I've found: https://stackoverflow.com/a/40165639/3870815

In that answer they use:

```
@ViewChildren('popContent') components:QueryList<CustomComponent>;
```

To build a list of those dynamically generated components. Highly recommend you check it out!

Comment: Thanks, this solved a problem I had with ng-bootstrap nav-tabs that were created in a ngFor. Having the same reference, tabs were changing simultaneously.

Answer (score 2):

Another way to allow this is to create a component that wraps the button and the ng-template

```
<div *ngFor="let member of members">
    <popover-button [member]="member"></pop-over-button>
</div>
```

And have the following in the popover-button component

```
<ng-template #popContent>Hello, <b>{{member.name}}</b>!</ng-template>
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" [ngbPopover]="popContent" popoverTitle="Fancy content">
    I've got markup and bindings in my popover!
</button>
```