# Multiple autocomplete in same page with different source in angular 4 with angular material

Tags: angular, angular-material, angular-material2

Multiple autocomplete in same page with different source in angular 4 with angular material:

source :https://material.angular.io/components/autocomplete/examples

I have followed the material autocomplete example and trying to add one more autocomplete in the same page but the source is different but not working.

Is formcontrol is creating problem ??

```js
import {Component} from '@angular/core';
import {FormControl} from '@angular/forms';

import 'rxjs/add/operator/startWith';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/map';

@Component({
  selector: 'autocomplete-overview-example',
  templateUrl: 'autocomplete-overview-example.html',
})
export class AutocompleteOverviewExample {
  stateCtrl: FormControl;
  testCtrl: FormControl;
  filteredStates: any;
  filterTests:any;
tests = [
    'Nawab',
    'Alaska',
    'Arizona',
    'Arkansas',
    'California'];
  states = [
    'Alabama',
    'Alaska',
    'Arizona',
    'Arkansas',
    'California',
    'Colorado',
    'Connecticut',
    'Delaware',
    'Florida',
    'Georgia',
    'Hawaii',
    'Idaho',
    'Illinois',
    'Indiana',
    'Iowa',
    'Kansas',
    'Kentucky',
    'Louisiana',
    'Maine',
    'Maryland',
    'Massachusetts',
    'Michigan',
    'Minnesota',
    'Mississippi',
    'Missouri',
    'Montana',
    'Nebraska',
    'Nevada',
    'New Hampshire',
    'New Jersey',
    'New Mexico',
    'New York',
    'North Carolina',
    'North Dakota',
    'Ohio',
    'Oklahoma',
    'Oregon',
    'Pennsylvania',
    'Rhode Island',
    'South Carolina',
    'South Dakota',
    'Tennessee',
    'Texas',
    'Utah',
    'Vermont',
    'Virginia',
    'Washington',
    'West Virginia',
    'Wisconsin',
    'Wyoming',
  ];

  constructor() {
    this.stateCtrl = new FormControl();
    this.filteredStates = this.stateCtrl.valueChanges
        .startWith(null)
        .map(name => this.filterStates(name));
        this.testCtrl = new FormControl();
    this.filteredTests = this.testCtrl.valueChanges
        .startWith(null)
        .map(name => this.filterTests(name));
  }

  filterStates(val: string) {
    return val ? this.states.filter(s => s.toLowerCase().indexOf(val.toLowerCase()) === 0)
               : this.states;
  }
  filterTests(val: string) {
    return val ? this.tests.filter(s => s.toLowerCase().indexOf(val.toLowerCase()) === 0)
               : this.tests;
  }

}


/**  Copyright 2017 Google Inc. All Rights Reserved.
    Use of this source code is governed by an MIT-style license that
    can be found in the LICENSE file at http://angular.io/license */
```

```html
<md-input-container>
  <input mdInput placeholder="State" [mdAutocomplete]="auto" [formControl]="stateCtrl">
</md-input-container>

<md-autocomplete #auto="mdAutocomplete">
  <md-option *ngFor="let state of filteredStates | async" [value]="state">
    {{ state }}
  </md-option>
</md-autocomplete>
<md-input-container>
  <input mdInput placeholder="Test" [mdAutocomplete]="auto" [formControl]="testCtrl">
</md-input-container>

<md-autocomplete #auto="mdAutocomplete">
  <md-option *ngFor="let test of filteredTests | async" [value]="test">
    {{ test }}
  </md-option>
</md-autocomplete>
```

Answer (score 61, accepted):

You have the same reference variable (`#auto`) assigned to both inputs. The id needs to be unique for each input. Change your second `input` and `md-autocomplete` to following:

```
<md-input-container>
  <input mdInput placeholder="Test" [mdAutocomplete]="autoTest" [formControl]="testCtrl">
</md-input-container>
<md-autocomplete #autoTest="mdAutocomplete">
  <md-option *ngFor="let test of filteredTests | async" [value]="test">
    {{ test }}
  </md-option>
</md-autocomplete>
```

Link to [Plunker Demo](https://plnkr.co/edit/TbfrrpbBdYHVElhkLUqi?p=preview)

---

**For cycles** like `*ngFor` there is no need to create dynamically named template variable, since

> Template reference variables are scoped to the template they are
>   defined in. A structural directive creates a nested template and,
>   therefore, introduces a separate scope. ([This question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44441164/7573844))

Comment: Thanks Bro..i have one more doubt..When i am placing autocomplete and md -select in same page both are not properly align ..as md-select is coming little up.

Comment: Can you please add one md-select option on the same plunker example, u'll fell the same.

Comment: Thanks.. I was running in circles trying to figure this one out.

Comment: How to call autocomplete reference to a different component?