# Multiple autocomplete material angular shows same dropdown

Tags: angular, angular-material

My multiple dropdowns work but it shows the same value. I am following [angular material component](https://material.angular.io/components/autocomplete/overview).

I have created different filtered for each array object still shows the same dropdown.

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { FormControl } from '@angular/forms';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Observable';
import { startWith } from 'rxjs/operators/startWith';
import { map } from 'rxjs/operators/map';
import { UsersComponent } from '../users/users.component';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-accommodation',
  templateUrl: './accommodation.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./accommodation.component.css']
})
export class AccommodationComponent {

      myControl = new FormControl();

      country = [
        new UsersComponent('United States'),
        new UsersComponent('Canada'),
        new UsersComponent('Brazil'),
        new UsersComponent('India'),
        new UsersComponent('China'),
        new UsersComponent('Japan'),
      ];

      nationality = [
        new UsersComponent('American'),
        new UsersComponent('Canadian'),
        new UsersComponent('Indian'),
        new UsersComponent('Chinese'),
        new UsersComponent('African'),
        new UsersComponent('Japanese'),
      ];


      countryFilter: Observable<UsersComponent[]>;
      nationalityfilter: Observable<UsersComponent[]>;

      ngOnInit() {
        this.countryFilter = this.myControl.valueChanges
          .pipe(
            startWith<string | UsersComponent>(''),
            map(value => typeof value === 'string' ? value : value.name),
            map(name => name ? this.filter(name) : this.country.slice()),
          );
        this.nationalityfilter = this.myControl.valueChanges
          .pipe(
            startWith<string | UsersComponent>(''),
            map(value => typeof value === 'string' ? value : value.name),
            map(name => name ? this.filter(name) : this.nationality.slice()),
          );
      }


      filter(name: string): UsersComponent[] {

        return this.country.filter(option => option.name.toLowerCase().indexOf(name.toLowerCase()) === 0),
               this.nationality.filter(option => option.name.toLowerCase().indexOf(name.toLowerCase()) === 0);       
      }

      displayFn(users?: UsersComponent): string | undefined {
        return users ? users.name : undefined;
      }

}
```

Below is the HTML code, where I have changed id as per [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45934244/multiple-autocomplete-in-same-page-with-different-source-in-angular-4-with-angul). Still doesn't work.

```html
        <div class="col-sm-6">
        <mat-form-field class="example-full-width">
            <input type="text" placeholder="Country" aria-label="Country" matInput [formControl]="myControl" [matAutocomplete]="auto">
            <mat-autocomplete #auto="matAutocomplete" [displayWith]="displayFn">
                <mat-option *ngFor="let option of countryFilter | async" [value]="option">
                    {{ option.name }}
                </mat-option>
            </mat-autocomplete>
        </mat-form-field>
    </div>
    <!-- col end -->
    <div class="col-sm-6">
        <mat-form-field class="example-full-width">
            <input type="text" placeholder="Nationality" aria-label="Nationality" matInput [formControl]="myControl" [matAutocomplete]="auto">
            <mat-autocomplete #autoNationality="matAutocomplete" [displayWith]="displayFn">
                <mat-option *ngFor="let option of nationalityfilter | async" [value]="option">
                    {{ option.name }}
                </mat-option>
            </mat-autocomplete>
        </mat-form-field>
    </div>
    <!-- col end -->
```

After @Mjstk update it worked awesome but still shows some error
[image]

Answer (score 25, accepted):

You have to change the name of the second autocomplete, so it doesnt link to the first one aswell, change "auto" to "autoNationality": [matAutocomplete]="autoNationality">

```
<mat-form-field class="example-full-width">
            <input type="text" placeholder="Nationality" aria-label="Nationality" matInput [formControl]="myControl" [matAutocomplete]="autoNationality">
            <mat-autocomplete #autoNationality="matAutocomplete" [displayWith]="displayFn">
                <mat-option *ngFor="let option of nationalityfilter | async" [value]="option">
                    {{ option.name }}
                </mat-option>
            </mat-autocomplete>
        </mat-form-field>
```

Comment: It worked but it still shows error when I focus input. Any idea ? I have posted screenshot of error in question.

Comment: try to change [formControl]="myControl" to: formControlName="myControl"

Comment: yes it did a job. I also changed it to the .ts file. it work nice

Comment: Well It did the job nicely but it should be more clear in the docs... Or I don't know maybe I missed something

Comment: Thank you! I agree this needs to be made more clear in the docs. I was pulling my hair out trying to figure this one out.

Answer (score 0):

Please change the following:

1. `auto` to `autoNationality`, `[matAutocomplete]="autoNationality"`
2. `[formControl]="myControl"` -> `formControlName="myControl"`