# How to declare variable as ID in angular 4?

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-material

I was trying to declare a variable as ID of autocomplete. But it throws an error.

```
<div formArrayName="AddonSection">
  <div [formGroupName]="i" *ngFor="let section of marketForm.get('AddonSection')['controls']; let i = index">
    <mat-form-field>
      <input (keyup)="autocompleteFilter($event.target.value, i)" type="text" matInput formControlName="GroupName" [matAutocomplete]="auto"+"i">
      <mat-autocomplete #auto+i="matAutocomplete">
        <mat-option *ngFor="let group of marketGroups" [value]="group">
          {{ group }}
        </mat-option>
      </mat-autocomplete>
    </mat-form-field>
  </div>
</div>
```

In this above code, I was looping autocomplete inside formArray.  So i tried to concat Array Index with string and gave it as ID:

```
#auto1="matAutocomplete", #auto2="matAutocomplete"
```

And

```
[matAutocomplete]=auto1, [matAutocomplete]=auto2
```

But I am getting an error, tried with a single quote and {{}} and different options a but no luck. Could someone please tell me how to give variable as ID for Autocomplete?

Comment: See this link : https://stackoverflow.com/a/38582320/4632215 Hope it helps

Comment: Use `#auto` https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44440879/dynamic-template-reference-variable-inside-ngfor-angular-2

Comment: When add multiple autocomplete with same ID #Auto i am getting first autocomplete selected value in the second autocomplete.