# How to create different template reference variable for items in *ngFor angular

Tags: angular

I have a list of button attributes and I want the buttons to have different template reference variables, but I'm rendering them using *ngFor. How can I set the reference variable to be #button1, #button2, etc. I need to set the template reference variable to be the ToolTipDirective for that button.

**Why I need to do this:** The button's tooltip is not accessible in Firefox (the tooltip doesn't show when using TAB). So, to make the tooltip show, I need the button to be: `<button #button1=bs-tooltip (focus)="button1.toggle()" (blur)="button1.toggle()" [tooltip]=button.tooltip" >{{button.text}}</button>`. Using the same template reference variable creates a problem where the tooltip for a button is shown when the focus is on another button (both tooltips are shown, but only 1 should show).

Code:

```
<li *ngFor="let button of buttons">
   <button #button1=bs-tooltip (focus)="onFocus(button1) [tooltip]=button.tooltip" >{{button.text}}</button> --> how can I set #button1?
</li>
```

Comment: Your template looks correct and should work as expected. Every variable passed into `onFocus` will have an unique reference to the individual button.  Are you doing anything else with the button?

Comment: It has a bug that `onFocus()` is called at the wrong time because of the same template reference variable

Comment: hm. Try passing in `$event` - onFocus($event): https://angular.io/guide/user-input

Comment: It should work for the same name. Can you add more code? What is the ToolTipDirective?

Comment: I want onFocus to perform some action with the ToolTipDirective of that button, but passing $event does not solve that. I cannot get the ToolTipDirective from the event.

Comment: ToolTipDirective is when you set [tooltip]="Tooltip Text", it shows a text when hovering over.

Comment: Ok, where do you use `#button1` in that directive?

Comment: as argument to `onFocus(button1)` which accepts a ToolTipDirective

Comment: And it doesnt work?

Comment: Check second part of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44440879/dynamic-template-reference-variable-inside-ngfor-angular-2/44441164#44441164

Comment: it works, but my point is if I have 10 buttons that I populate using an *ngFor, how would I set `#button1=bs-tooltip`, `#button2=bs-tooltip`, etc.?

Comment: Why do you want that? Just use `#button="bs-tooltip"` they will be different for each item in loop

Comment: It's not different. I tried it and I got a bug where the tooltip was showing up when it shouldn't because the buttons have the same template reference variable.

Comment: @yurzui I added a complete explanation of why I need to do it that way

Comment: @matchi are you able to create a reproduce-able stackblitz? The buttons should all be different.

Answer (score 0):

you can bind id property and then use document to get the html element

here is an example

**app.component.ts**

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css']
})
export class AppComponent {

  onClick(foo) {
    console.log(foo)
  }

  getElementById(id) {
    return document.getElementById(id);
  }
}
```

**app.component.html**

```
<button (click)="onClick(getElementById('foo'))">click </button>

<input [id]="'foo'">
```