# How can I programmatically trigger ripple effect on Angular MatListItem?

Tags: angular, angular-material

In Angular material you have the lovely ripple effect on a lot of the components. When you click on a mat-list-item the ripple effect happens.

Now with buttons and many other components you can trigger the ripple effect with `button.ripple.launch(...)` but with mat-list-item I see no such functionality. I'd like to be able to do it to inform users of changes made to the list.

Does anyone know of a workaround? I've tried dispatching 'click' from the MatListItem's _getHostElement(), but to no avail.

**EDIT**

Thanks to everybody who's helped out! I think in the end I'll just design my own list component that gives me access to its MatRipple directive. I've forked pr41's stackblitz to have the situation be similar to what I have (a list generated with *ngFor) and if anyone knows what to put here:

```
this.listChildren.map((item: MatListItem) => {
  // item is the MatListItem. How do I access its ripple directive?
});
```

that would be great!

The Fork: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-mmjda4-ssoajs?file=app%2Flist-overview-example.ts

Answer (score 4):

As of recent versions of Material, there is now a Ripples module ([docs here](https://material.angular.io/components/ripple/overview)) that allow for the customization and programmatic triggering of ripples in a component, such as `mat-list-item`.

Programmatic triggering involves the following:
First, we make our list and attach the `matRipple` directive. In my example, I'm using a button click to trigger the ripple, so an event handler has been added as well:

```
<mat-list role="list" matRipple>
  <mat-list-item role="listitem">Item 1</mat-list-item>
  <mat-list-item role="listitem">Item 2</mat-list-item>
  <mat-list-item role="listitem">Item 3</mat-list-item>
</mat-list>
<button mat-raised-button color="accent" (click)="triggerRipple()">Trigger Ripple</button>
```

Within the component, we grab the `matRipple` using `ViewChild`, allowing us to call `launch()` on the ripple to trigger the actual ripple effect:

```
@ViewChild(MatRipple) ripple: MatRipple;

triggerRipple() {
  this.ripple.launch({centered: true});
}
```

[Here's a stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-mmjda4?file=app%2Flist-overview-example.ts) showing this sample in action; click the button to cause a ripple in the `mat-list`. Naturally, you can move the `matRipple` directive to any component if you'd like the ripple effect applied to something else. Take a look at the docs for more configuration options available.

Comment: Thanks very much for that! I saw that on the angular material site for ripple. My problem is that the list is generated from an `*ngFor` (as one would expect) and I'm able to access the MatListItem using @ViewChildren and looping through the QuerySelector. If I were to add a matRipple directive to each MatListItem, how could I access specifically the MatRipple of that MatListItem?

Comment: I've forked your stackblitz to be in the same situation as I find myself in (you can see it in my edited question) - I can loop through the matListItems but don't know how to access their ripple directive.

Answer (score 0):

You can try [dynamic template reference variable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44440879/dynamic-template-reference-variable-inside-ngfor-angular-2). It works to me.

```js
import { MatRipple } from '@angular/material/core';

export class FooComponent {
    @ViewChildren(MatRipple) rippleList: QueryList<MatRipple>;

    ngAfterViewInit() {
        let ripples = this.rippleList.toArray()
        ripples.forEach(res => {
                // res is the instance of each matRipple
        })
    }

}
```

But It confused to me that I can use it perfect in my project but I can't reappear it in stackblitz:(