# Programmatically trigger ripple on Angular material icon button

Tags: angular, angular-material

I have two angular material buttons.
My goal is to programmatically let the button ripple when a certain key is pressed.

Take a look at the stack-blitz project:
https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-material-button-vphppo

Is there a way to let the button ripple on click or on key-press exactly one time?

**I tried these examples**
[How can I programmatically trigger ripple effect on Angular MatListItem?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52957504/how-can-i-programmatically-trigger-ripple-effect-on-angular-matlistitem)

- But this lets the button ripples two time on click.

Comment: Updated answer below for keypress.

Comment: Thank you. I should have use `@ViewChild('btnNext', {static: false}) btnNext: MatButton;` instead of MatRipple

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`MatButton` provides direct access to the `Ripple` in the current Material:

```
  @ViewChild('btnNext', {static: false}) btnNext: MatButton;

  @HostListener('document:keypress', ['$event'])
  handleKeyboardEvent(event: KeyboardEvent) { 
    if( event.key === 'a') {
      this.btnNext.ripple.launch({centered: true})
    }
  }
```

The above will proc the ripple when 'a' is pressed.

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-3xgxiw

Comment: But it should ripple on keydown. Not on clicking another button.