# Angular 7 - make #parameter="ngModel" input as a dynamic name

Tags: angular, angular2-ngmodel

I there a way to create the "ngModel" parameter in template driven forms as a dynamic name (for ex. by loop)?

I wish to get something like:

```
<div *ngFor='let d of items; let i = index;'>
    <input type="text" name="street" 
    [(ngModel)]="d.surname" #surname{{d.myindex}}="ngModel">
</div>
```

where the "d.myindex" is the dynamic name.

Comment: You shouldn't need to do that. You should use `#surname="ngModel"`.

Comment: but I am creating several input fields by the array length. I can't call them all the same name.

Comment: Please show us how you want to use the `#surname` template reference variable.

Comment: Thats the example I wrote. I have the items array, and I wish to create input fields based on this array.

Comment: The example shows that you want to define the `#surname` variable, but not what you want to do with it. Do you need it?

Comment: I need it this way so I could use another field for: surname{{d.myindex}}.control.markAsTouched()

Comment: Please add the code and the context where you want to do that. It can probably be done with the same template variable name for all the input fileds. By the way, you cannot define these variables with dynamic names.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know what is your requirement to make it dynamic but...  *TemplateRef* is not for that.

**TemplateRef** => it is block scoped though it has the same name while looping.
You can use the `ViewChildren` decorator which returns all items of an `ItemType` and the remaining magic `Angular` does it for you.

#### component.ts

```
<div *ngFor="let i of [0, 1, 2, 3]" #items>
     <button (click)="onClick(items, i)">Click on item {{ i }}</button>
</div>
```

#### .html

```
@ViewChildren('items') items: ItemType<ElementRef>;

 onClick(item, i) {
    console.log('item clicked : ', item);
    console.log('index of item : ', i);
    console.log('all items : ', this.items)
 }
```

I'm not clear, what do you want but I just showed a way with `click` event please apply it for your `input`

for more details please check: https://stackoverflow.com/a/44441164/5835354