# Angular 7, elementRef not correct

Tags: javascript, angular

i have created component `autocomplete` and i was using it just fin till i had to user 2 of those component in 1 view, i saw that `dropdown` in template is referenced to previous instance of my `autocomplete` component

```
@Component({
  selector: 'app-autocomplete',
  templateUrl: './autocomplete.component.html',
  styles: []
})
export class AutocompleteComponent implements OnInit, OnChanges {
  delayId;

  @ViewChild('dropdown')
  dropdown;
  @ViewChild('element')
  input;
....
}
```

and template

```
<div class="form-group" style="position: relative;">
  <label for="{{buttonId}}">{{buttonCaption}}</label>
  <input #element (keyup)="sendKeyStrokes(element.value)"
         type="text" class="form-control"
         id="{{buttonId}}"
         aria-describedby=""
         placeholder="{{buttonCaption}}">
  <ng-content></ng-content>
  <div #dropdown <-- **this is wrong** class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="btnGroupDrop1">
      <span *ngFor="let option of options"
        class="dropdown-item"
        (click)="optionClick(option)">
        {{option.caption}}
      </span>
    </div>
</div>
```

can i create reference `#` dynamically ? or someone can point me to right direction

Comment: possible duplicate? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44440879/dynamic-template-reference-variable-inside-ngfor-angular-2

Comment: ok, i found what caused this, and now i'm sure that every component is encapsulated :D the  `AutocompleteComponent` is working good i had error in parent component