# How to add template reference id dynamically in ng-template

Tags: angular

I have json object which holds some html strings. Need to create multiple ng-template with unique reference variable.

```
   <div *ngFor="let el of ElementList">
    <ng-template #el.id>
      <div [innerHtml]="el.html"></div>
    </ng-template> 
   </div>
```

Here is my ElementList array

```
 ElementList = [
    {id: 'h1', html: '<h1>sample heading</h1>'},
    {id: 'h2', html: '<h2>sample heading</h2>'},
    {id: 'h3', html: '<h3>sample heading</h3>'},
  ];
```

Can anyone help me on this

Comment: `<ng-template *ngFor="let item of ElementList" [id]="item.id">....`

Comment: Why do you want to have unique template reference variable names? How will you use these variables?

Comment: Just change your `ng-template` as in @Hamza Neffati answer

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Dynamic template reference variable inside ngFor (Angular 2)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44440879/dynamic-template-reference-variable-inside-ngfor-angular-2)

Comment: @dcg - How is that supposed to work? What HTML element will have the `id`?

Comment: @ConnorsFan Do you suggest the `[id]=el.id` should be inside the inner div? I think it should. Thanks

Comment: @dcg - It depends on what the OP wants to do with the `id`. Or if he wants a template reference variable. That is not clear for me.

Comment: Thanks for the comments. I need unique template reference variable

Comment: I dont understand what do you mean with 'unique template reference variable'. Why `[id]=el.id` approach does not work?
Maybe this is relevant:
https://blog.angularindepth.com/handle-template-reference-variables-with-directives-223081bc70c2

Answer (score -2):

Try this :

```
<div *ngFor="let el of ElementList">
  <ng-template [id]="el.id">
    <div [innerHtml]="el.html"></div>
  </ng-template> 
</div>
```

Comment: `ng-template`s are not HTML elements.

Comment: Getting this error

Template parse errors:
Property binding id not used by any directive on an embedded template. Make sure that the property name is spelled correctly and all directives are listed in the "@NgModule.declarations". ("

<div *ngFor="let el of ElementList">
[ERROR ->]<ng-template [id]="el.id">
<div [innerHtml]="el.html"></div>
</ng-template> 
")

Answer (score -2):

Why not you use @ViewChildren.

```html
<div *ngFor="let el of ElementList">
  <ng-template #elem>
      <div [innerHtml]="el.html"></div>
    </ng-template> 
</div>
```

In your component class access the template reference variable through ViewChildren, like this

```js
 @ViewChildren(TemplateRef) elem : QueryList<TemplateRef<any>>;
```

Now you can access templates e.g.

```js
console.log(this.elem.toArray());
```