# How to Dynamically Set Angular # Template Reference Variables

Tags: angular

I have a list of groups populated from a database and use ngFor to iterate through in the html.

```
<mat-card  *ngFor="let group of groups" >
  <mat-card-title #group > {{group}}  </mat-card-title>
</mat-card>
```

I would like the **#group** to be the value of the group, not hardcoded. That way I can have another component to scroll to the different template variables.

How can I do this? Thanks.

Comment: Could you share the same in stackblitz as the question is not very much clear to me.

Answer (score 4):

As per my knowelage template reference variables are uniquely scoped to the templates that they are defined in. And structural directive creates a nested template and therefore, introduces a separate scope, in your case `mat-card-title`.

So basically using group template reference variable inside `<mat-card-title #group >` will do in your case since it will hold unique scope for itself.

```
<mat-card  *ngFor="let group of groups" >
  <mat-card-title #group > {{group}}  </mat-card-title>
</mat-card>
```

> For more details please refer answer by @yurzui [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44440879/dynamic-template-reference-variable-inside-ngfor-angular-2)

Comment: Let me expand, I want to be able to scroll to each of the groups. So sure the scope may not be conflicting but I do need the value of the group from the ngFor.

Comment: So cant you use a method inside the`<mat-card-title (click)="getGroup(group)" #group > {{group}}  </mat-card-title>` like this to get the group or something silmilar?

Comment: Always you can use a ViewChildren to get in a QueryList the elements -ende the Nativeelement and so, but as SelakaN say **inside** the *ngFor you can use **group** without conflict