# How to use Angular ngbootstrap popover in angular for loop

Tags: angular, ng-bootstrap

I am using ngbPopover like following

```
<ng-template #mytemp>
    <my-editor></my-editor>
</ng-template>
 <button type="button" class="btn" placement="bottom-left" [ngbPopover]="mytemp">
    Show
</button>
```

But I want to use this in a *ngfor loop.

```
let items =[ { id:1, settings: "s1" }, { id:2, settings: "s2" }];

<div *ngFor="let item of items">
    <ng-template #item.id>
        <my-editor></my-editor>
    </ng-template>
     <button type="button" class="btn" placement="bottom-left" [ngbPopover]="item.id">
        Show
    </button> 
</div>
```

but it did not work.

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44440879/dynamic-template-reference-variable-inside-ngfor-angular-2. This question is almost identical

Comment: The problem with your solution is that you cannot create a dynamic template reference

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Dynamic template reference variable inside ngFor (Angular 2)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44440879/dynamic-template-reference-variable-inside-ngfor-angular-2)