# how to access dynamically created ID in angular in a html div using #

Tags: html, angular, dynamic-programming

`<li *ngFor="#item of items" [id]="item.id">some text</li>`
How to access dynamically created ID in angular in a html div using #

I want to use the ID created in the above code using # dynamically in a div like in the below code.
`<div #(id created in above code)></div>`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Dynamic template reference variable inside ngFor (Angular 9)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44440879/dynamic-template-reference-variable-inside-ngfor-angular-9)

Comment: @Tanner ID doesnt work like in the link you showed.

Comment: Is the div where you want to use the dynamic id inside the ngFor? Also why do you have # before #item in the loop? Can you please share a bit more code to represent your goal?