# bind #element to element created with *ngFor

Tags: angular, viewchild

I am using `*ngFor` to create a bunch of `div`s. I would like to get my hands on one of them and get its width.

.html

```html
<div #elReference *ngFor="let el of elements> HEHE </div>
```

.ts

```ts
@ViewChild("elReference") elReference: ElementRef;
```

Apparently, you cannot use `ViewChild` with `*ngFor`, because `elReference` remains `undefined`.

How do you get element reference created with `*ngFor`?

Comment: Take a look at this thread: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40165294/access-multiple-viewchildren-using-viewchild

Comment: Thanks. I tried   @ViewChildren("elReference") elReferences: QueryList<ElementRef>; , but still getting an undefined value for elReferences.

Comment: I used it in onInit(). it appears ngAfterViewInit is mandatory.

Comment: You have to use ngAfterViewInit because you must wait the template to be parsed and the DOM mounted.

Comment: Thanks. I am indeed getting the clientWidth now. For some reason, it is rounded to nearest integer. This code         console.log(this. elReference.nativeElement.clientWidth);
returns 25, although the actual width in browser is 25.11. $("element").outerwidth() also returns 25.11

Answer (score 12, accepted):

There is no way to add a template variable selectively,
but you can add a marker selectively and then filter by that:

```
<div #elReference [attr.foo]="el.x == 'foo' ? true : null" *ngFor="let el of elements"> HEHE </div>
```

```
@ViewChildren("elReference") elReference: QueryList<ElementRef>;

ngAfterViewInit() {
  console.log(this.elReference.toArray()
      .filter(r => r.nativeElement.hasAttribute('foo')));
}
```

Comment: Danke schön. So far I've always used ViewChild and #elReference inside of onInit(). Why do I need to use ngAfterViewInit in this case?

Comment: If `*ngFor` depends on data passed to `@Input()` it won't be rendered yet.

Comment: `toArray()` is not a JavaScript function, and TypeScript returns error as expected

Comment: @M98 `toArray()` is a method of `QueryList` created by `@ViewChildren` . I should have been more clear in my answer about that.

Comment: Okay, Now with the edit, it makes sense! Thanks a lot

Comment: Make sure to indeed use 'true : null'. I used true & false values first, they become strings as attributes thus were always truthy.

Answer (score 5):

There is a more complicated, but more correct way with a directive.

```html
<!-- app.component.html -->
<div *ngFor="let el of elements" [id]="el.id"> HEHE </div>
```

```js
// div-id.directive.ts
import { Directive, Input, ElementRef } from '@angular/core';

@Directive({
  selector: 'div[id]',
})
export class DivIdDirective {
  @Input() id: number;

  constructor(ref: ElementRef<HTMLDivElement>) {
    this.el = ref.nativeElement;
  }

  el: HTMLDivElement;
}
```

```js
// app.component.ts
export class AppComponent implements AfterViewInit {
  // ...
  @ViewChildren(DivIdDirective) els: QueryList<DivIdDirective>;

  ngAfterViewInit(): void {
    console.log(this.els.map(({id, el}) => ({id, el}));
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

An simple and elegant approach is to leverage the component model of Angular. Move the content of the iterated element into a component.

Instead of

```
<div ngFor="let a of aList">
  <div #a>{{a}}</div>
</div>
```

You would have

```
<div ngFor="let a of aList">
  <app-a [a]="a"></app-a>
</div>
```

with app-a being

```
<div #a>{{a}}</div>
```