# Access ngfor first element from component

Tags: angular, typescript, redux, observable, ngrx

I need to get the first element of an ngfor from the component to get it's offset value.

the only thing I've found so far is using `let first = first;` in the template which does not help

I've a reference to my list but I don't know how to use it for that :

`@ViewChild('list') list: ElementRef;`

How can I do that ?

Comment: Where do you need to access it? In the template or in the ts?

Comment: As in the title, from  the component.ts

Comment: It'd be useful to see some code.

Comment: You need `@ViewChildren`  - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40165294/access-multiple-viewchildren-using-viewchild

Comment: I'll add some but it's that basic of the basic. an empty component with only an array, a template with only a ngfor. that display the array. I'm trying to access the first element of the ngfor to get the offset

Comment: If your component already has the array you use in the `ngFor`, can you not just do `array[0]` ?

Comment: array[0] would give me the data displayed, what I'm trying to get is the element from the dom. @sharedul that is the correct one thank you ! You can answer if you want