# querySelectorAll equivalent in TypeScript

Tags: javascript, typescript

I'm actually training to use TypeScript with Angular, 
an equivalent to a simple document.querySelectorAll in Vanilla JavaScript is  @ViewChild .

But it take only one element of the HTML.

I wanted to do it but with an array document.querySelectorAll, with for example 4 div with the same class.

Can someone know how could I query them to increment like an array ?

Thanks in advance ! :D

Comment: No way !! `document.querySelectorAll` is not equivalent to `@ViewChild` .

Comment: Yeah I know :/ But I'm looking for what the equivalent of document.querySelectorAll is equal to in TypeScript ? :)

Comment: document.querySelectorAll is a DOM API, it's completely independent from Typescript. I have no idea what @ViewChild is, i know you are talking about decorators but if you are talking about a specific framework then make it clear with the tags in your question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `document.querySelectorAll`in TypeScript as it is a standard API. However, if you are using Angular, you should use `@ViewChild` and `QueryList`. You can find more info in this question: [Access multiple viewchildren using @viewchild](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40165294/access-multiple-viewchildren-using-viewchild)

Comment: Ah okay I understand, that's because I'm using Angulat and QueryList should the what I just need.

Comment: Big Thanks :) And have a nice day !