# Differentiate viewChild with same name in ngFor

Tags: angular

In my html component, I have an `*ngFor` loop which generates multiple elements like so:

```
<div *ngFor="let item of items">
  <p #itemName>{{item.name}}</p>
</div>
```

And in my .ts component to access the `<p>`, I'm doing:

```
@ViewChild('itemName') itemName: ElementRef;
```

And as an example of me doing something with it:

```
this.itemName.nativeElement.focus();
```

My issue is that since there can be multiple `p` tags, there will be  multiple instances of `itemName` in the .ts file and when trying to do something with it, such as the example above, the first instance of `itemName` will be focused.

How can I determine which instance of `itemName` I'm currently on?

Comment: you can use `@ViewChildren` check this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40165294/access-multiple-viewchildren-using-viewchild

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Access multiple viewchildren using @viewchild](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40165294/access-multiple-viewchildren-using-viewchild)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `@viewChildren` to select multiple elements with same template reference variables. You should convert the `QueryList` to array using `toArray()` method in order to loop over the elements.

```
import { ViewChildren, QueryList } from '@angular/core';

....

@ViewChildren('itemName') itemName: QueryList<ElementRef>;

ngAfterViewInit() {
  this.itemName.toArray().forEach(el => {
    el.nativeElement.focus();
});
}
```

Comment: @Bear you can also iterate over a QueryList using for(let item of this.itemName){...}. If only need first element you can use this.itemName.first.nativeElement.focus()