# Declare View child conditionally

Tags: angular, viewchild

I have input box inside two divs that render conditionally.

**html**

```
<div ngIf="show==true">
<input #ref />
</div>

<div ngIf="show==true">
<input #ref />
</div>
```

**.ts**

```
@ViewChild('ref ') ref : ElementRef;

ngOnInit(){

 if(someCondition){
  show = true;
 }

Observable.fromEvent(this.ref .nativeElement, 'keyup');
}
```

It shows the undefind ref as ref variable declared before ngOnInit

I believe we cannot initialize viewchild later,

What could be alternate solution.

Thanks

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40165294/access-multiple-viewchildren-using-viewchild

Comment: You have two different DOM elements rendered conditionally. What is the need of accessing the with a common reference ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you need to access that viewchild component like as below. 
Means you have to make use of  "ngAfterViewInit" (implement AfterViewInit ), as child component doesnt get avaiable when "ngOnit" runs

```
  @ViewChild('ref ') ref : ElementRef;

  ngAfterViewInit() {
    console.log('Values on ngAfterViewInit():');
    console.log("ref:", this.ref);
  }
```