# Angular Dynamic Components: @ViewChildren get ViewContainerRef for every component in QueryList

Tags: angular, angular-dynamic-components

I am building a dialog with dynamic tabs that can receive a component to be placed in the tab body. I am having a hard time creating multiple dynamic components using @ViewChildren. I have successfully done this with a single component and @ViewChild in the past quite easily.

**Here is my template:**

```
<mat-tab *ngFor="let tab of tabs" [label]="tab.label">
     <ng-template #comp></ng-template>
</mat-tab>
```

**Here is my component logic:**

```
@ViewChildren("comp") dynComponents: QueryList<any>;


public ngAfterContentInit() {
  this.tabs.forEach(tab => {
     const factory = this._resolver.resolveComponentFactory(tab.component);
     console.log(this.dynComponents); // Returns undefined.

     // this.componentRef = this.vcRef.createComponent(factory);
  });
}
```

My dynComponents are undefined even when hard-coding components in the Template. I need to seemingly get the ViewContainerRef from this dynComponents QueryList, but I am not sure why it is not populating at all. I used this post for reference: [Post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40165639/8384588)

Comment: try use ngAfterViewInit. Anyway -I must check it- I think that if your templates are not  in view when AfterViewInit happens you need subscribe to `this.dynComponents.changes.subscribe(res=>{..here you has your dnyComponent..}`

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The [`@ViewChildren`](https://angular.io/api/core/ViewChildren) in the component is not working because it is missing the `read` metadata property indicating `ViewContainerRef`.

### Component

```js
import {
  AfterContentInit, Component, ComponentFactoryResolver, QueryList, Type, ViewChildren, ViewContainerRef
} from '@angular/core';


@Component({
  selector: 'dynamic-dialog',
  templateUrl: './dynamic-dialog.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./dynamic-dialog.component.scss']
})
export class DynamicDialogComponent implements AfterContentInit {
  @ViewChildren('comp', { read: ViewContainerRef })
  public dynComponents: QueryList<ViewContainerRef>;

  public tabs = [];

  constructor(private _resolver: ComponentFactoryResolver) {}

  ngAfterContentInit() {
    this.dynComponents.map(
      (vcr: ViewContainerRef, index: number) => {
        const factory = this._resolver.resolveComponentFactory(
          this.tabs[index].component);
        vcr.createComponent(factory);
      }
    )
  }
}
```

p.s. Dynamic content may be loaded using lifecycle hook [`AfterContentInit`](https://angular.io/api/core/AfterContentInit) or [`AfterViewInit`](https://angular.io/api/core/AfterViewInit).

Comment: This works as expected. Nice solution! Anyone who views this post in the future, make sure to store your comp refs when creating them and destroy them on ngOnDestroy!

Answer (score 3):

In my project i do this to build dynamically the components:

App Component

```
   <div *ngFor="let field of fields">
        <app-dynamic-component [field]="field" ></app-dynamic-component>
    </div>
```

App-dynamic-component.ts

```
  @ViewChild(DynamicComponentDirective, {static: true}) adHost: DynamicComponentDirective;

...
loadComponent() {
    const componentFactory = 
        this.componentFactoryResolver.resolveComponentFactory(this.field.component);

    const componentRef = <any>viewContainerRef.createComponent(componentFactory);
}
```

App-dynamic-component.html

```
<ng-template dynamic-component></ng-template>
```

Finally my dynamic-component Directive

```
import { Directive, ViewContainerRef } from '@angular/core';

@Directive({
  selector: '[dynamic-component]',
})
export class DynamicComponentDirective {
  constructor(public viewContainerRef: ViewContainerRef) { }
}
```