# Angular Dynamic component ViewChildren always undefined

Tags: angular

based on this stack overflow post ([Angular Dynamic Components: @ViewChildren get ViewContainerRef for every component in QueryList](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57721310/angular-dynamic-components-viewchildren-get-viewcontainerref-for-every-compone)), I'm trying to add dynamic component in an ngFor.

The issue is that the ViewChildred referencing the ng template is always undefined

**Here my template**

```
<div *ngFor="let service of loadedServices; let i = index;">
  <accordion [closeOthers]="true">
    <accordion-group panelClass="b0 mb-2">
      <div accordion-heading>
        <small>
          <em class="fa fa-plus text-primary mr-2"></em>
        </small>
        <span><b>{{service.description}}</b></span>
      </div>

      <ng-template #serviceBookmark></ng-template>


    </accordion-group>
  </accordion>
</div>
```

**Here my component**

```
export class DatasourceDetailsComponent implements OnInit,AfterContentInit  {
constructor(private resolver: ComponentFactoryResolver) { }

@ViewChildren('serviceBookmark', { read: ViewContainerRef })
public dynComponents: QueryList<ViewContainerRef>;

ngAfterContentInit() {
    this.dynComponents.map(
      (vcr: ViewContainerRef, index: number) => {
        const factory = 
    this.resolver.resolveComponentFactory(ServiceFormComponent);
    vcr.createComponent(factory);
  }
);
}
}
```

Unfortunately in AfterContentInit the dynComponent is always undefined...
What I'm doing wrong?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should try with ngAfterViewInit or a setter:

```
components: QueryList<ViewContainerRef>;

@ViewChildren('serviceBookmark', { read: ViewContainerRef })
set dynComponents(comps: QueryList<ViewContainerRef>) {
    console.log(comps);
    this.components = comps;
}
```

This should work.

Comment: there is probably an issue... comps is a ViewContainerRef in your sample... and dynComponents is defined as QueryList<ViewContainerRef>... It gives me error... could you please help me? I'm new to angular. thanks

Comment: Sorry, I've fixed the example