# Angular Get list of dynamic components

Tags: angular, loops, dynamic, components, viewchildren

I need to loop throughout over nested child components inside on div. I try that with **ViewChildren** but I got only a list of created components and when I create a dynamic component, Unfortunately, the list is not updated. I tried to manually run the change detector too which is no effect at all.

[MyProject](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-sf93zj?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html)

Comment: I guess you should have a look at: https://stackoverflow.com/a/57726154/14693246