# Count of filtered ngfor angular

Tags: angular, ngfor

Is there an easier way to get the count of actual displayed results in an ngFor that has a nested ngIf without?

```
<div *ngFor="let stuff of things">
   <ng-container *ngIf="stuff.key === 'value'">
     **I'd like an easier way to get the result of this *ngIf .length and use it elsewhere**
   </ng-container>
</div>
```

I tried to use @ViewChildren and hoped for;

```
@ViewChildren('myContainerRef') containerRef: QueryList<any>

<label>Count {{ myContainerRef.length }}</label>
<div #myRef *ngFor="let stuff of things">
</div>
```

but get undefined result. Is my last resort doing a filter on the incoming array to get the count and assign it public vars? Or is there an easier way to get the count of an ngfor results that match a condition / are displayed?

Comment: Did you check https://stackoverflow.com/a/57726154/2490286

Comment: Why don;t you just use another variable on ts side and have a filteredArray and then you can use filteredArray.length anywhere you want and you don't need an *ngIf in your template.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use ViewChildren in `AfterViewInit` at the earliest. You can search for `ng-container` but would be better to search the elements you're after with `#myRef` so it would count only the ones you are interested in.

```html
<div *ngFor="let stuff of things">
  <ng-container #myRef>
    {{ stuff }} **I'd like an easier way to get the result of this *ngIf .length
    and use it elsewhere**
  </ng-container>
</div>
<br />
TotalContainers: {{ containersCount }}
```

```js
@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css'],
})
export class AppComponent implements AfterContentChecked {
  @ViewChildren('myRef') containers: QueryList<ElementRef>;

  things = Array.from(Array(10).keys());
  containersCount: number;

  constructor() {}

  ngAfterContentChecked() {
    this.containersCount = this.containers?.length;
  }
}
```

Working example: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-vpq5n4?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts

Comment: Since this answers the original inquiry though I ended up going another route, thank you.

Answer (score 2):

I would change the logic to allow the filtering to occur in the .ts file and then you have both the iterable and the count...

The following allows the filtering of the original array and the length is the number of matching items

```
.component.ts
   const filteredThings= things.filter(x => x.key === 'value');

.component.html
   <div *ngFor="let thing of filteredThings">
      {{ thing.xyz }} {{filteredThings.length}}
   </div>
```

Comment: This is what I ended up doing anyway before I came back to check answers so +1

Answer (score -1):

You can create pipe like this

```ts
@Pipe({
  name: 'filterThings',
})
export class FilterThingsPipe implements PipeTransform {

  transform(array: Thing[], value: string): Thing[] {
    return array.filter(item => item.key == value);
  }

}
```

then use it inside template

```html
<div *ngFor="let stuff of things | filterThings:'val1'; let length = count">
  {{stuff.key}} of {{length}}
</div>
```

Pipe will return filtered array, and as ngFor provides count as one of it's exported values [docs here](https://angular.io/api/common/NgForOf#local-variables) you can assign in to template variable (length = count) inside ngFor expression

Comment: Your answer could be improved by adding more information on what the code does and how it helps the OP.