# Clear data from the same component when clicking the button

Tags: angular, typescript

In a component, I am using the same library twice (out of necessity). When you submit the form, only one component is cleaned, when in fact both should be cleaned.

I don't know why a component is only cleaned.

Can someone identify the problem or how can I delete the data in the two components?

[DEMO](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ppptxy?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts)

**CODE**

```
 @ViewChild(DxHtmlEditorComponent, {static: false}) dxHtmlEditor;


 clearAll(){  
   this.dxHtmlEditor.instance.reset();
   alert("clear works!")
 }
```

**html**

```
<dx-html-editor>
    <dxi-mention
        valueExpr="text" 
        displayExpr="text"
        [dataSource]="employees"
    ></dxi-mention>
</dx-html-editor>



<dx-html-editor>
    <dxi-mention
        valueExpr="id" 
        displayExpr="text"
        [dataSource]="users"
    ></dxi-mention>
</dx-html-editor>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're currently getting only one instance with `ViewChild`.  Change it to `ViewChildren` and loop over them:

```
import { Component, ViewChildren, QueryList } from "@angular/core";
import { DxHtmlEditorComponent } from "devextreme-angular";

@Component({
  selector: "my-app",
  templateUrl: "./app.component.html",
  styleUrls: ["./app.component.css"]
})
export class AppComponent {
  @ViewChildren(DxHtmlEditorComponent) editors: QueryList<DxHtmlEditorComponent>;

  clearAll() {
    this.editors.forEach(editor => editor.instance.reset())
  }
}
```

[Blitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-gkadnz?file=src/app/app.component.ts)

Answer (score 0):

You need to use [ViewChildren](https://angular.io/api/core/ViewChildren) because [ViewChild](https://angular.io/api/core/ViewChild) references only to a single instance(first occurrence).

Note that the *list* would be [QueryList](https://angular.io/api/core/QueryList) *of* `DxHtmlEditorComponent`

more answers could be found here:

[Access multiple viewchildren using @viewchild](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40165294/access-multiple-viewchildren-using-viewchild)