# Angular how to get index from viewChildren queryList items?

Tags: angular, typescript

I am watching for my radio buttons with :

```
  @ViewChildren('radioButton') radioButton: QueryList<MatRadioButton>;
```

Later I want to get the first and make it checked :

```
  public clickEmitFirst() {
    this.radioButton.forEach((radio,index) => {
        console.log(index);
        radio.checked = true;
        this.clickEvent.emit({ id: this.parentId, item: this.item });
    });
  }
```

> The problem is that index is always 0 (3 console logs with 0)

How to fix that ?

Comment: When you just want to use the first, why not https://angular.io/api/core/QueryList#first?

Comment: Maybe [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40165639/6444705) can help you ?

Comment: I think this queryList gives me 3 queries with 1 item , bcs first and last is the same

Answer (score 1):

I've made a demo in which everything works (looping through viewChildren and getting the index). Try to compare this, maybe you've made a typo somewhere.
[stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-gbobkc?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts)

Answer (score 0):

My foult, I was calling viewChildren function in my child component which has only one radioButton (Multiple child components with single radioButtons), thats why I was getting 0 index in each component.