# Angular. "*ngIf; else" alternative with custom component

Tags: javascript, angular

I want simplify the built in directive `ngIf; else` with a custom component. The idea is eg.:

```
@Component({
   selector: 'app-main',
   template: `
   <ng-condition>
     <ng-if *ngCondition="number <= 5">
        Number {{ number }} is minor or equal 5
     </ngif>
     <ng-else-if *ngCondition="number <= 10">
        Number {{ number }} is minor or equal 10
     </ng-else-if>
     <ng-else>
        Number {{ number }} is major of 10
     </ng-else>
   </ng-condition>`
})
export class AppComponent {
    number = 6;
}
```

output

```
Number 6 is minor or equal 10
```

The idea is:

- `*ngCondition` directive is a custom directive like `ngIf`
- `ng-condition` component must have `ng-if` and `ng-else-if`, `ng-else` is optional.

Components `ng-if`, `ng-else-if` and `ng-else` are just:

```
@Component({
   selector: 'ng-if',
   template: '<ng-content></ng-content>'
})
export class NgIf {}

@Component({
   selector: 'ng-else-if',
   template: '<ng-content></ng-content>'
})
export class NgElseIf {}

@Component({
   selector: 'ng-else',
   template: '<ng-content></ng-content>'
})
export class NgElse {}
```

`*ngCondition` directive is:

```
@Directive({
  selector: '[ngCondition]'
})
export class NgConditionDirective {

  constructor(
    private element: ElementRef,
    private templateRef: TemplateRef<any>,
    private viewContainer: ViewContainerRef
  ) {}

  @Input()
  set ngCondition(val: boolean) {
    if(val) {
      this.viewContainer.createEmbeddedView(this.templateRef);
    } else {
      this.viewContainer.clear();
    }
  }
}
```

The `ng-condition` is:

```
@Component({
   selector: 'ng-condition',
   template: '<ng-content></ng-content>'
})
export class NgCondition {
   // ... HERE THE MAGIC CODE TO WRITE
}
```

The idea is, `ng-condition` component retrive all child component (`ng-if`, `ng-else-if` and `ng-else`) and:

1. check if a `ng-if` is present (and only one is available) otherwise raise an exception;
2. if a `ng-if` is visible (`ng-if *ngCondition` is true) all `ng-else-if` and `ng-else` are destroyed;
3. if a `ng-else-if` is visible, the `ng-else` is destroyed;
4. Only one `ng-else` is avalable, otherwaise an exception is raised;
5. `ng-if`, `ng-else-if` and `ng-else` only can be placed into `ng-condition`;
6. `ng-if`, `ng-else-if` must have a `*ngCondition` directive  otherwaise an exception is raised;
7. `ng-else` can't have a `*ngCondition` directive  otherwaise an exception is raised;

The main problem is detect change of `<ng-content></ng-content>` into `ng-condition` componet and retrive all child component for write all the logic.

**Final questions**:

1. How detect change of `<ng-content></ng-content>` and retrive all the child components?
2. How check if a child component have a specific directive?

*I'm also searching some inspiration, tips and trick for start to develop my idea.*

Thanks!

**UPDATE**

I have developed my idea: https://www.npmjs.com/package/ng-condition

Comment: You need to use ngAfterContentChecked to detect changes in ng-content and to retrieve child components you can use querylist, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40165294/access-multiple-viewchildren-using-viewchild

Comment: @GowthamRajJ thanks, querylist seem have a subscribe method for detect changes

Comment: Ya, but not sure about your 2nd question though.

Comment: Maybe this could be helpful - https://angular.io/api/common/NgIf#showing-an-alternative-template-using-else

Comment: @GowthamRajJ i have developed my idea: https://www.npmjs.com/package/ng-condition

Comment: Oh Nice !!, congrats for publishing.