# Access Checkbox values on form submit ionic 2

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, ionic2

I have multiple checkbox on my view page and I want to access those selected values on form submit. How Can I access it?. I have seen on SO, that we can access checkbox using change event, but it doesn't work for me. Below is my code.

**Note :** I am using model driven approach (Form Builder), I would like to see answer in model driven way, if possible.

```
<ion-row>
<ion-col col-sm-6 col-md-6 col-lg-3 col-xl-4 *ngFor="let location of company_data.data.locations; let i=index" [hidden]="location.location_id == location_id_Ref.value">
  <ion-item>
    <ion-label>{{location.location_name}}</ion-label>
    <ion-checkbox value="{{location.location_id}}" (click)="updateCheckedOptions(location, $event)" formControlName="worksites"></ion-checkbox>
  </ion-item>
</ion-col>
</ion-row>
```

Comment: look at this it might help you http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43423333/angular-2-how-to-get-the-multiple-checkbox-value

Comment: no its not working, getting error `Uncaught (in promise): TypeError: control.registerOnChange is not a function`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all, you should not use `formControlName` with your checkboxes, you want to use an `formArray` just like suggested in the link provided by Arun. Let's just declare an empty formArray to which we push or remove `location`'s.

```ts
this.myForm = this.fb.group({
  worksites: this.fb.array([])
})
```

Then your template we make a slight change from the other example, we swap `(change)` to `(ionChange)` instead:

```html
<ion-item>
  <ion-label>{{location.location_name}}</ion-label>
  <ion-checkbox (ionChange)="updateCheckedOptions(location, $event.checked)"></ion-checkbox>
</ion-item>
```

and `updateCheckedOptions` function:

```ts
updateCheckedOptions(location:Object, isChecked: boolean) {
  const worksites = <FormArray>this.myForm.controls.worksites;
  // if target checked, push to formarray, else remove
  if(isChecked) {
    worksites.push(new FormControl(location));
  } else {
      let index = worksites.controls.findIndex(x => x.value.location_id == location.location_id);
      worksites.removeAt(index);
  }
}
```

### [Demo](http://plnkr.co/edit/irzz1lc1Qk4TFP4bHM1q?p=preview)

Comment: Thanks a lot , its working perfectly now, can you suggest some more links where I will get more information on handling user input in ionic 2

Comment: Sorry can't help you there really, never used ionic myself other than here on SO. The best I can do is to point you to the official docs: http://ionicframework.com/ Sorry, can't be of more help really :(