# all checkboxes selected on selecting specific checkbox among multiple checkboxes which has [(ngModel)] in angular4

Tags: angular, checkbox

Here 'n' is incremental and 0 by default when i click "NEXT" it increments by 1 
, which retirives objects respectively

```
statement 1:
============

#let option of question[0].options

 here,lets assume "option" will have 1st question's option. and outputs the 
 following using *ngFor

 **<input name="0"  value="{{q1_option_value}}" [(ngModel)]="option_value[0]" 
type="checkbox"/><span>{{q1_option_value}}</span>**

 **<input name="1"  value="{{q1_option_value}}" [(ngModel)]="option_value[1]" 
type="checkbox"/><span>{{q1_option_value}}</span>**

 =========================
'n' value incremented by 1
 =========================


 **<input name="0"  value="{{q2_option_value}}" [(ngModel)]="option_value[0]" 
type="checkbox"/><span>{{q2_option_value}}</span>**

 **<input name="1"  value="{{q2_option_value}}" [(ngModel)]="option_value[1]" 
type="checkbox"/><span>{{q2_option_value}}</span>**
```

now when i select a checkbox in question1's option, that selection presist 
to next question also...

## Here is my code sample !

```
<form>
 <div class="choice">
  <div *ngFor="let option of question[n].options; let i = index">
   <input name="{{i}}"  value="{{option}}" [(ngModel)]="option_value[i]" 
    type="checkbox"/><span>{{option}}</span>
  </div>
 </div>
</form>
```

Comment: this might help you check it https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43423333/angular-2-how-to-get-the-multiple-checkbox-value

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Is technologies_value an array? If so have you tried this?

```
[(ngModel)]="technologies_value[i]"
```

Comment: OK. Well you have multiple checkboxes so the ngModel needs to be able to bind each checkbox to its own value. At the moment you are binding them all to the same variable (technologies_value) so they all get the same value.

Comment: thanks for your answer, but after implementing your solution i met with another problem so i re-edited my question please take a look

Comment: OK. I may not entirely understand the example but the ngModel will need to have one value for every separate checkbox. In your example you have: option_value[0] and then option_value[0] repeated again for the next 'N'. If N goes up to 1 (meaning it was zero and then a 1), then you would need option_value[0], option_value[1], option_value[2] and option_value[3]

Comment: <div *ngFor="let option of question[n].options; let i = index">
   <input name="{{i}}"  value="{{option}}" [(ngModel)]="option_value[i]" 
    type="checkbox"/><span>{{option}}</span>
  </div>    **here, n performs as index & i performs as key -- hence i solved this already**.. thank you guys...