# Dynamic material checkboxes

Tags: angular, angular-reactive-forms

I have an array of services with following structure:

- `addonOptions[]`
- `hasAddons`
- `serviceId`

`addonOptions[]` has objects with following structure

- `serviceId`
- `addonName`
- `addonId`
- `isChecked`

I loop through services and generate dynamic checkboxes where `serviceId`s match. Now I want to check the checkboxes by default in case `isChecked` is true. But the following is not working:

```html
<ng-container *ngFor="let service of serviceOptions; let i = index">
    <label *ngIf="service.hasAddons"><b>AddOns</b></label>
    <p *ngFor="let addon of service.addonOptions">
        <ng-container *ngIf="service.serviceId == addon.serviceId">
            <md-checkbox
                formControlName="addonName"
                type="checkbox"
                [ngModel]="addon.isChecked"
                [checked]="true"
                (change)="selectServiceAddon($event.checked,addon)">
                    {{ addon.addonName }}
                </md-checkbox>
        </ng-container>
    </p>
</ng-container>
```

Comment: is this a reactive form? If so, your first issue is that you cannot capture several values with one formcontrol.

Comment: yes it's reactive form, and issue is the same!! Could you please provide some help in that case?

Comment: How did it go with the answers, did some answer solve your issue? :)

Answer (score 2):

You cannot capture a single value with a single formcontrol, what you want is a formArray, where we push the checked items. Here's a simplified example, where your data you are iterating looks like this:

```ts
addonOptions = [{addonName:"name1", isChecked: false},
                {addonName:"name2", isChecked: true},
                {...}]
```

When we build the form, we just declare an empty form array:

```ts
this.myForm = this.fb.group({
  addons: this.fb.array([])
});
```

Then if we actually don't need to care about the values until we submit the form, we can set the values to the form after submitting the form.

So in template we just iterate the array you have like so:

```html
<div *ngFor="let addon of addonOptions">
  <input type="checkbox" [(ngModel)]="addon.isChecked" [ngModelOptions]="{standalone: true}"> 
     {{addon.addonName}}
</div>
```

and do not add any form control.

Upon submit, we filter the values that have `isChecked` as true and apply that filtered array as the formArray, like so:

```ts
onSubmit() {
  let formArr = this.addonOptions.filter(x => x.isChecked === true)
  this.myForm.setControl('addons', this.fb.array([...formArr]));
}
```

[**DEMO**](http://plnkr.co/edit/0q2cZUsqCjtNQIhxWfFm)

If you want, you could also dynamically add/remove fields when checked/unchecked, then do a little spinoff of this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/43424244/6294072

Answer (score 0):

Could you try to use :

```
<md-checkbox 
  formControlName="addonName" 
  type="checkbox" 
  [checked]="addon && addon.isChecked" 
  (change)="selectServiceAddon($event.checked,addon)">
  {{addon.addonName}}
</md-checkbox>
```

Comment: Would you try to make a plunker ?