# Multiple Checkbox value in angular2

Tags: json, angular

I have one user model and one role model. I want to send value of role into db using checkbox in angular2 in http put request. I have one table user_role and I want to send role_id into that table. For the I am fetching all roles and showing it in html like this:

```
 <a *ngFor="let role of roles">
   <input type="checkbox" [value]="role.name" [(ngModel)]="user.role_id" [ngModelOptions]="{standalone: true}"/>&nbsp;<b>{{role.name}}</b>
 </a>
```

Now I want, if I will check multiple checkboxes the multiple values should go into database. I am new in angular2. Could anyone please help me in getting this?

Comment: I'd use a reactive form and FormArray: https://stackoverflow.com/a/43424244/6294072

Answer (score 0):

I have created a sample demo where you can understand how multiple checkbox value can be sent to server

**here is my .ts file code**

```
roles: Array<String> = [
{
  "name":"qa",
  "isSelected": false
},
{
  "name":"developer",
  "isSelected": false
},
{
  "name":"manager",
  "isSelected": false
},
{
  "name":"BA",
  "isSelected": false
},];
sendDataToServer() {
alert(JSON.stringify(this.roles)); }
```

I have a json **roles** and a function **sendDataToServer**  that displays the final json that is to be sent on server

here is my .html code

```
 <a *ngFor="let role of roles">
 <input type="checkbox" [value]="role.name" [(ngModel)]="role.isSelected"        [ngModelOptions]="{standalone: true}"/>&nbsp;<b>{{role.name}}</b>
 </a>
<br><br>
<input type="button" value="Send Data On Server "    (click)="sendDataToServer()"/>
```

So I have 4 checkbox and I have bind these checkbox with **isSelcted** property of json. As soon as user click on checkbox the value changes false to true.

when user click on sendDataToServer button then we have the **updated** isSelected values.

Hope this will help you. :)