# How to get data from multiple check boxes using Ionic 2/3?

Tags: angular, typescript, ionic2, ionic3

Hi I am a newbie to the Ionic 2 here I am facing an issue related to the checkboxes here what I doing I want to get the values from checkboxes after checking it here I am using the reactive approach so I want to get the data using the `formControlname`

```
<ion-list *ngFor="let item of collection">
            <ion-list-header>
              Skills
            </ion-list-header>

            <ion-item >
              <ion-label>{{item.label}}</ion-label>
              <ion-checkbox ></ion-checkbox>
            </ion-item>

          </ion-list>






this.collection=[
                {
                    "label": "English",
                    "checked": false
                },
                {
                    "label": "Computer",
                    "checked": false
                },
                {
                    "label": "Sales",
                    "checked": false
                },
                {
                    "label": "Driving",
                    "checked": false
                },
                 ]
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Angular how to get the multiple checkbox value?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43423333/angular-how-to-get-the-multiple-checkbox-value)

Comment: https://ionicframework.com/docs/api/components/select/Select/                                  This can be a useful link