# How do I send values of selected checkbox as an array to the function?

Tags: html, angular, typescript

Im fairly new to working with angular and was wondering if there is a simple way to first check if the checkbox is selected. If it is selected, I want to pass it to the `saveOptions` function. If more than one is selected, I would like to pass them all and save them to an array of options. Can someone help me out?

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { forEach } from '@angular/router/src/utils/collection';
import { Options } from 'selenium-webdriver/ie';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css']
})
export class AppComponent {
  options: any = []



  saveOptions(x:any[]){
     x.forEach(element => {
      this.options.push(element);
    });
  }

}
```

```html
<ul class="option-row">
    <div class="option-group">
        <li><input type="checkbox"  id="option-1" value="1" required> <label for="option-1">Option 1</label></li>
        <li><input type="checkbox"  id="option-2" value="2" required> <label for="option-2">Option 2</label></li>
        <li><input type="checkbox"  id="option-3" value="3" required> <label for="option-3">Option 3</label></li>
    </div>
    <!--Want to know how to check if the checkbox is selected and pass the selected options to the method-->
    <button type="button" (click)="saveOptions();">Submit</button>
</ul>
```

Comment: You can see this answer. It will better for you. [Click here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43424244/5919039)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One way is subscribing to valueChanges of the form, like this:

```
export class AppComponent implements OnInit {
  options: any = []
  model = { optionOne: false, optionTwo: false, optionThree: false }
  formChangesSubscription;
  @ViewChild('form') ngForm: NgForm;

  ngOnInit() {
    this.formChangesSubscription = this.ngForm.form.valueChanges.subscribe(x => {
      console.log(x);
    })
  }

  saveOptions(x: any[]) {
    x.forEach(element => {
      this.options.push(element);
    });
  }
}
```

```
<form #form="ngForm">
    <ul class="option-row">
        <div class="option-group">
            <li><input type="checkbox" [(ngModel)]="model.optionOne" name="optionOne" id="option-1" value="1" required> <label for="option-1">Option 1</label></li>
      <li><input type="checkbox" [(ngModel)]="model.optionTwo" name="optionTwo" id="option-2" value="2" required> <label for="option-2">Option 2</label></li>
      <li><input type="checkbox" [(ngModel)]="model.optionThree" name="optionThree" id="option-3" value="3" required> <label for="option-3">Option 3</label></li>
    </div>
    <!--Want to know how to check if the checkbox is selected and pass the selected options to the method-->
    <button type="button" (click)="saveOptions();">Submit</button>
</ul>
</form>
```

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-j5idkn?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts

Answer (score 1):

you can this in dynamic way with the help of **`ngFor`** and **`[value]`** of the `div` element.

use an array for your `li` elements, modify your template and component some thing like below.

> **Component.html**

```
 <ul class="option-row">
    <div *ngFor="let li of listedValue" class="option-group">
        <li><input type="checkbox"  id="option-{{li}}" [value]="l" required (click)="setCheckbox($event,li)"> <label for="option-{{li}}">Option 1</label></li>
    </div>
        <!--Want to know how to check if the checkbox is selected and pass the selected options to the method-->
        <button type="button" (click)="saveOptions();">Submit</button>
</ul>
```

> **Component.ts**

```
name = 'Angular 5';
  listedValue: any = [1, 2, 3];
  options: any = []

  setCheckbox(event: any,value: any) {
     if (event.target.checked)
       this.options.push(value)
     else
       this.options= this.options.filter(val => val != value);
  }

  saveOptions() {
   console.log(this.options);
  }
```

I have created a [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular6-wmypt8?file=app/app.component.ts) for your case check it once. I hope this will solve your issue :)

Comment: this will keep adding to the array on checking and unchecking.

Comment: don't get confused between `stack` and `array`, js provide stack functions on any array. pop only removes the top element thus output will be different on checking and unchecking and they are not mutation friendly.

Answer (score 1):

I am just gonna extend ganesh's answer here!

`Component.html`

```
<form #form="ngForm">
     <ul class="option-row">
    <div *ngFor="let li of listedValue; index as i" class="option-group">
        <li><input type="checkbox"  id="option-{{li}}" [value]="l" required (click)="setCheckbox(li, i)"> <label for="option-{{li}}">Option {{ i }}</label></li>
    </div>
        button type="button" (click)="saveOptions();">Submit</button>
</ul>
</form>
```

`component.ts`

```
name = 'Angular 5';
  listedValue: any = [0, 1, 2];
  options: any = []

  ngOnInit(){}

  setCheckbox(event: any, index: number) {
    if(!this.options.includes(event)){
      this.options = [...this.options, event];
    }else {
      this.options = this.options.filter((item) => item !== event);
    }
  }

  saveOptions() {
   console.log(this.options);
  }
```

[StackBlitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-rhzbzn?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts)

Answer (score 0):

i think you can use form control reactive form it will help you