# Is it possible to bind to multiple checkboxes with an array of boolean values in a template driven form?

Tags: angular, angular2-template

I am aware of both [FormArray from reactive forms](https://angular.io/api/forms/FormArray) and the method of objects in an array or map as described in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34997128/angular-2-get-values-of-multiple-checked-checkboxes). Normally I would use the former, and if absolutely necessary the latter - but I would like to know if it is possible with **just** an array of `boolean` values.

**template**

```html
<div>
  <h2>Hello {{name}}</h2>
</div>
<input type="checkbox" *ngFor="let item of items; let i = index;" [(ngModel)]="items[i]"/>
```

**component**

```js
@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  template: `...`,
})
export class App {
  name:string;
  items = [false, false, true];
  constructor() {
    this.name = `Angular! v${VERSION.full}`
  }
}
```

With the files as above, clicking the first checkbox will change the value of other checkboxes. Is there a mistake I have made, or is this not possible in Angular?

Gif showing the incorrect behaviour:

[image: Gif showing the incorrect behaviour]

[Live example on Plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/PylLsE3banZTKf7J01AS)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The ngFor must be a level up in order to avoid the reference issue.

```
<div *ngFor="let item of items; let i = index;" >
     <input type="checkbox" [(ngModel)]="items[i]"/>
</div>
```

**[Updated Plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/K6iGUeOmrfOhXwORNEFA?p=preview)**

Comment: Having a look at the plunker I get a wrong behaviour if I initially click on the first checkbox. Any idea where this might come from? It seems that the initial values are taken correctly.

Comment: Thanks @JDC I'll look into it