# How to get checkbox value in angular 5 app

Tags: angular, angular-forms

I am working on Angular checkbox and need to read value either given `ng-true-value` / `ng-false-value` or boolean value not sure what I am missing from code. I am reading event but not sure which value to read??

### template

```
<div>

 <input 
    type="checkbox" 
    name="questionAnswerState" 
    ng-model="check"
    ng-true-value = "answerProvided"
    ng-false-value="questionAnswerNotProvided" 
    (change)="isAnswerProvided($event, check)"
    /> Answer Provided?
```

### component

```
 isAnswerProvided(event: any, check:any)
  {
    console.log("question answer not provided responseId:: ",this.responseId, " questionId::",this.questionId, "  check::", check );
    console.log(event);
  }
```

Comment: You need the true or false values ?

Comment: The snippet looks like AngularJs(v1.x)... not Angular (v2.0+)

Comment: yes................

Comment: i need angular 2 implementation

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're using Angular 2> you should use the `checked` attribute for using one way binding, that the UI will only read the value of `check`. Using this method you would have to update the `check` value in your component.

```
 <input 
    type="checkbox" 
    name="questionAnswerState" 
    [checked]="check"
    (change)="isAnswerProvided($event, check)"
    /> Answer Provided?
```

or if you're after two way binding, where the state is controlled completely by the UI you can use `ngModel` like this:

```
 <input 
    type="checkbox" 
    name="questionAnswerState" 
    [(ngModel)]="check"
    (change)="isAnswerProvided($event, check)"
    /> Answer Provided?
```

Comment: [checked]="check" return undefinded when I console.log in component

Comment: is `check` defined in your component. If not, just stick with the two way binding method of using `ngModel` or add `check: boolean` to your component

Comment: [(ngModel)]="check" worked, but still how to read value from $event for checkbox??

Comment: You don't need to read the value from the checkbox, your model is `check`, you only need to look at the value for `check` now.