# Get selected checkboxes values in Angular 5

Tags: angular, checkbox, angular5

I have a checkbox list control and am trying to get checked values into an array.

My models:

```
export class Order {
    Products: Product[];
    SelectedProducts: string[];
}

export class Product {
    Id: number;
    Title: string;
}
```

The snippet goes through the `Product` property and displays them as checkboxes:

```
    <div *ngFor="let product of orderService.order.Products">

        <label>
            <input type="checkbox" name="orderService.order.Products" value="{{product.Id}}" [(ngModel)]="product.checked" />
            {{product.Title}}
        </label>

    </div>
```

I can get the list of `orderService.order.Products` values from the checkboxes but how to filter them to get only checked values when submitting?

I based my code on the @ccwasden answer here: [Angular 2: Get Values of Multiple Checked Checkboxes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34997128/angular-2-get-values-of-multiple-checked-checkboxes) but my `Product` model does not have the `checked` property and it shouldn't have.

In my component I have:

```
get selectedOptions() {
    return this.orderService.order.Products
        //.filter(opt => opt.checked)
        .map(opt => opt.value)
}

submitorder(form: NgForm) {
    var selection = this.selectedOptions;

    [post order here]
}
```

but selectedOptions comes empty.

**EDIT**

This is the correct code for `selectedOptions()` method (note `opt.Id` not `opt.value` as above):

```
get selectedOptions() {
    return this.orderService.order.Products
        //.filter(opt => opt.checked)
        .map(opt => opt.Id)
}
```

But the main question remains - how to get checked options?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You've made a small mistake. Fix:

```
get selectedOptions() {
    return this.orderService.order.Products
        .filter(opt => opt['checked'])
        .map(opt => opt.Id);
}
```

Each 'opt' is a 'Product', so they don't have a 'value'.

On the other hand, I don't think `value="{{product.Id}}"` adds anything to the functionality as ngModel is actually the value of the input tag. Hope this helps :)

EDIT: If `checked` is not part of the model then simply write `product['checked']` instead of `product.checked`.

Comment: Thanks @slashpm but that wasn't my question. Yes indeed it is `opt.Id` originally, I pasted the wrong code here, but still don't know how to get checked values. `opt.checked` in filter will not build because the model does not have `checked` property