# Select all items in a checkbox Angular

Tags: angular

I have a list which has multiple checkboxes. I have made a function for single selection and multiple section and the user can get the data either for single selection and multiple selection.
Now the problem where I was stuck was when I remove selection of one check box in a list then select all checkbox should be deselected but I'm not able to do that.

Below is my code
HTML

```
  <div item-start class="checkbox-wrapper">
    <input type="checkbox" value="Select All" (change)="selectAllLineItem($event)">
  </div>

    <ion-card *ngFor="let putAwayPurchaseOrderListDetails of putAwayPurchaseOrderListDetailsData | filter:searchText; let i = index">
       <div class="checkbox-wrapper">
         <input class="form-check-input[(ngModel)]="putAwayPurchaseOrderListDetailsData[i].checked"  type="checkbox" >
       </div>
       <div>
         {{putAwayPurchaseOrderListDetails.PO_NUMBER}}
       </div>
    </ion-card>
```

TS

```
  selectedLineItem() {
    const selectedLineItem = this.putAwayPurchaseOrderListDetailsData.filter((putAwayPurchaseOrderListDetails) => putAwayPurchaseOrderListDetails.checked);
    this.navCtrl.push(PutAwayPurchaseOrderItemDetailsPage,{selectedLineItem})   
  }


  selectAllLineItem(event) {
    console.log(event)
    const checked = event.target.checked;
    this.putAwayPurchaseOrderListDetailsData.forEach(item => item.checked = checked);
  }
```

Comment: Isn't `putAwayPurchaseOrderListDetailsData` a bit of a mouthful?

Comment: @A.Chiesa it is, but the naming conventions are documented

Comment: It's 35 chars, even if it's documented, there is probably _something_ that went wrong with it.

Comment: I agree with you @A.Chiesa

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A quick, possible solution.

First, you split the ngModel double binding and create an handler:

```html
...
<input type="checkbox" value="Select All" [(ngModel)]="selectAllItems" (change)="selectAllLineItem($event)">
...
<input class="form-check input 
    [ngModel]="putAwayPurchaseOrderListDetailsData[i].checked"
    (ngModelChange)="onItemChange(i, $event)"
    type="checkbox" >
```

In the component ts:

```js
// new property:
selectAllItems: boolean = false;
...
onItemChange(itemIdx: number, isChecked: boolean) {
  this.putAwayPurchaseOrderListDetailsData[itemIdx].checked = isChecked;
  // doesn't if selectAllItems is already false.
  if (!isChecked) this.selectAllItems = false;
}
```

It should be enough.