# Angular 6 How To Get Values From Multiple Checkboxes and Send in From

Tags: angular, typescript, angular6

I'm trying to use mat-checkboxes as input in my form, but can't really find anything on docs regarding it.

Html

```
<section class="checkbox-section">
 <mat-checkbox [(ngModel)]="bChecked">Blogs</mat-checkbox>
 <mat-checkbox [(ngModel)]="wChecked">Web</mat-checkbox>
 <mat-checkbox [(ngModel)]="oChecked">Online News</mat-checkbox>
 </section>
```

Typescript

```
    public form = {
    name: null,
    email: null,
    birthday: null,
    company: null,
    interests: [],
    newsletter: null,
    address: null,
    password: null,
    password_confirmation: null,
  };
```

I'm trying to get the values of the checkboxes which are static and then push to my interests array

Comment: If value is static then you can do without bind checkbox with ngModel , You can use click event and based on that just pass value to your function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change your **HTML** as below.

```
<section class="checkbox-section">
  <mat-checkbox [(ngModel)]="bChecked" (change)="onCheckboxChagen($event, 'Blogs')">Blogs</mat-checkbox>
  <mat-checkbox [(ngModel)]="wChecked" (change)="onCheckboxChagen($event, 'Web')">Web</mat-checkbox>
  <mat-checkbox [(ngModel)]="oChecked" (change)="onCheckboxChagen($event, 'Online News')">Online News</mat-checkbox>
  </section>
```

As you need to use **static label** for checkbox value, you can pass a static label as the second argument to the `onCheckboxChagen` method. According to the value of the checkbox you can `push` and `pop` elements from the `interests` array.

**TS** changes should be as below.

```
  onCheckboxChagen(event, value) {

    if (event.checked) {

      this.interests.push(value);
    } 
    if (!event.checked) {

      let index = this.interests.indexOf(value);

      if (index > -1) {

        this.interests.splice(index, 1);
      }
    }
  }
```

[Working Demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-kfhwjl?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts)

Comment: Thanks this is more similar to what i was looking for

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if this might suit your requirement, but from what I understand all you need to do is change your code to something like this to get an info on which of the checkboxes are actually `checked`.

**Typescript**

```
public form = {
    ...
    interests: {
      blogs: false,
      web: false,
      onlineNews: false,
    },
    ...
  };
```

**HTML**

```
<section class="checkbox-section">
    <mat-checkbox [(ngModel)]="form.interests.blogs">Blogs</mat-checkbox>
    <mat-checkbox [(ngModel)]="form.interests.web">Web</mat-checkbox>
    <mat-checkbox [(ngModel)]="form.interests.onlineNews">Online News</mat-checkbox>
 </section>
```

I don't know how pushing the value `true` or `false` to any array makes any sense or give information on which input is checked.

Stackblitz [demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/mat-checkbox-r3cm13)

Comment: Thank you! this taught me some new techniques for checking matboxes

Answer (score 0):

You can add a change event on each of your `mat-checkbox` and call the following method to fullify your array:

(The below example could be upgraded using a single method with another parameter to know which checkbox had a change event)

```
<section class="checkbox-section">
 <mat-checkbox [(ngModel)]="bChecked" (change)="assignValues1($event)">Blogs</mat-checkbox>
 <mat-checkbox [(ngModel)]="wChecked" (change)="assignValues2($event)">Web</mat-checkbox>
 <mat-checkbox [(ngModel)]="oChecked" (change)="assignValues3($event)">Online News</mat-checkbox>
 </section>
```

In my example to access the new `boolean` value you can do like this :

```
assingValues1(event: MatCheckboxChange) {
var newVal = event.checked;
// your code here
}
```

Comment: It will return true/false, not the value